# Longest consecutive date streak in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Suppose I have the spreadsheet:

```
+-------+----------+
| Date  | Duration |
+-------+----------+
| 06/30 | 12:00    |
| 07/01 | 44:30    |
| 07/03 | 12:00    |
| 07/04 | 18:00    |
| 07/05 | 10:00    |
| 07/07 | 08:00    |
| 07/09 | 99:00    |
| 07/10 | 99:00    |
+-------+----------+
```

How could I find the length of the longest consecutive streak of dates via Excel? (in this example, it would be 3: 07/03, 07/04, 07/05).

I'd like to do this with an array formula, but I don't know how to compute consecutive differences in a column with an array formula. I would prefer to avoid a helper column, but it's not a deal-breaker.

Comment: Consecutive streak of dates means the column Date is sorted ascending and consecutive dates are those with 1 day difference?

Comment: @AxelRichter: yes, the column is always sorted ascending and contains no duplicates. Dates that are one day apart are consecutive, more than one day apart are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using one helper column this will be pretty simple.

[image]

Formulas:

`C3` downwards:

```
=IF(A3-A2=1,C2+1,0)
```

`E2`:

```
=MAX(C:C)+1
```

---

Found an array formula which works without helper column:

```
{=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF($A$3:$A$10001-$A$2:$A$10000=1,ROW($A$2:$A$10000)),IF($A$3:$A$10001-$A$2:$A$10000<>1,ROW($A$2:$A$10000))))+1}
```

Will work for dates in column `A` from `A2` up to `A10000`.
But I'm pretty sure that the solution with helper column is better in terms of performance and readability.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the check mark on this because I realized it would require me to know how many rows I would have in advance (the formula needs to be in every row that has data). If there's a way to apply this formula to an entire column, please let me know.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db#bmfillformulas -> You can automatically fill a formula downward, for all adjacent cells that it applies to, by double-clicking the fill handle of the first cell that contains the formula. For example, cells A1:A15 and B1:B15 contain numbers, and you type the formula =A1+B1 in cell C1. To copy that formula into cells C2:C15, select cell C1 and double-click the fill handle.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that does work.  My concern was really that I will be frequently adding new dates to the spreadsheet, and this approach means I'd have to constantly sync up the formula with the new rows.  I'm lazy! I think I'll wait one more day for any answer.  But thanks for your help!

Comment: How about using a [Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-867f3add-0522-493c-94ab-b1b9933f46ca) aka ListObject? Those expand their formula columns automatically if rows were added.