# Counting the max number of times a value occurs consecutively

Tags: excel

I have a list of users with the number of times they have been file checked in a 12 month period. I want to identify (in column H) how many consecutive months there has been NO file check for that user. Eg :

```
   A      B    C     D      E     F      G
User    |Oct |Nov | Dec  | Jan | Feb  | Mar
A       | 0  | 1  | 1    | 0   | 0    | 0 
B       | 1  | 1  | 0    | 0   | 1    | 0 
C       | 0  | 0  | 1    | 0   | 0    | 0
D       | 2  | 0  | 0    | 0   | 1    | 1
```

- Cell H2 should contain 3 as the there were no file checks on 3 consecutive months (Jan, Feb and March) for User A
- Cell H3 should contain 2 as there were no file checks on 2 consecutive months (Dec, Jan) for User B
- Cell H4 should contain 3 as the largest consecutive run of 0's is 3 (Jan, Feb, Mar)
- Cell H5 should contain 3 as the there were no file checks on 3 consecutive months (Nov, Dec and Jan) for User D

I know a simple COUNTIF would give me the total number of 0's for each user, but I want to calculate how many consecutive months and, where there has been more than one 'block' of consecutive 0's, what the longest period is.

Comment: worth looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341683/longest-consecutive-date-streak-in-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inelegant, but it appears to work:

```
=MAX(IF(IFERROR(FIND(REPT("0",ROW($1:$6)),CONCAT($B2:$G2)),0),ROW($1:$6),0)) [Ctrl+Shift+Enter]
```

It iterates through the numbers yielded by `ROW($1:$6)` to find the maximum number of zeroes in the concatenation of your per-month values in each row. Enter it as an array formula into H2 and fill down.